# typescript uses generics to reorganize read-only array types

Tags: typescript

I tried to restructure the type of the read-only array, but it didn't work:

```
const store: Record<string, any> = {
  aaa: '123',
  bbb: null,
  ccc: []
}

const getValues = <Keys extends readonly string[]>(keys: Keys): ReadonlyArray<[Keys[number], unknown]> => {
  return keys.map((key) => ([key, key in store ? store[key] : null]))
}

const keyArr = ['aaa', 'bbb'] as const
getValues(keyArr)  // current getValues function types:  const getValues: <readonly ["aaa", "bbb"]>(keys: readonly ["aaa", "bbb"]) => readonly ["aaa" | "bbb", unknown][]

// I want:  const getValues: <readonly ["aaa", "bbb"]>(keys: readonly ["aaa", "bbb"]) => readonly [["aaa", unknown], ["bbb", unknown]]
```

Here is the typescript [Playground code link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmAuGAlJoEBMA80CAlmAOYA0MAhmAJ4B8MAvDAN4CwAUDNVVWgHIAjACYAzAPJceAIzlowAVwA2yqdxjAtaANoBdLgF8uXUJFikkUAGpVlipBGYw8AaSS0nSAB5QkYHCdkKhxwZVo4KGIyfXoACgBrDwg0d08ASjRMELDaAEEEBCpaPB00iB0lAFsZJAQ9SkUwBLAQAHcwPUYmRg4NZChFBDAYJM8AOiqqAAc4xI905kY4nTHKMZgSSMQkGAB%20beRVjz0YBRVlPXT0oxNOM2hRjwKEZx0BPipJGAE5GQFTlQnA8oFxLDY7A4IPN8oVFjAAPQIzRDZBgWBQWjTVA8EEwcG2eyONB4YKhMDhGA6ABEn2plGpf2pXRhKRgZNyVNpfHpMEZcmZix67KQOQpERpdJgAB8%20UzGs1Wh09Po7kiYABJGBtGhQNCacCPAmQ4kuDnirl0hlMlljNnmymSnnWgVXJYisWOp1UXlNFrtTqUGnymB%20pWdAycIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the tuple using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmAuGAlJoEBMA80CAlmAOYA0MAhmAJ4B8MAvDAN4CwAUDNVVWgHIAjACYAzAPJceAIzlowAVwA2yqdxjAtaANoBdLgF8uXUJFikkUAGpVlipBGYw8AaSS0nSAB5QkYHCdkKhxwZVo4KGIyfXoACgBrDwg0d08ASmZGDg1kKEUEMBgkzwA6AFsqAAc4xI9MpkY46R4YHRLKEpgSSMQkGAB%20XuR2jz0YBRVlPXSWzKonVjbXbqKSkAAzGDSIPV0dnVc9SkUwBLAQAHcwceNOO9NwaGKPAEEEBGcdAT4qSRgBHIZAJxgtNE8oFxLDY7A4IHVaO8EJkYAB6VGaArIMCwKC0KqoHhmZ7Q2z2RxoPDBUJgcJtABEv3plHpQPpeniJRSMGpYQiOkZfGZMFZcnZDUYvNp-MFVHpMAAPiK2Sczhdrnp9CZOOiYABJGCXGhQNDg8wwUmwikuKV0gVMllsjkI7m2mUO5VimZZHlIEJ8tr2oWq85XG6UAUqmCnUMagycIA). Mapping over a tuple type using a mapped type also produces a tuple as a result [since TypeScript 3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).

```
const getValues = <Keys extends readonly string[]>(keys: Keys) => {
  return keys.map((key) => (
    [key, key in store ? store[key] : null])
  ) as { [K in keyof Keys]: [Keys[K], unknown] }
}
```

TypeScript is not able to correctly understand that the type of the resulting array matches the return type. So a type assertion is needed.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNICcCmAuGAlJoEBMA80CAlmAOYA0MAhmAJ4B8MAvDAN4CwAUDNVVWgHIAjACYAzAPJceAIzlowAVwA2yqdxjAtaANoBdLgF8uXUJFikkUAGpVlipBGYw8AaSS0nSAB5QkYHCdkKhxwZVo4KGIyfXoACgBrDwg0d08ASmZGDg1kKEUEMBgkzwA6AFsqAAc4xI9MpkY46R4YHRLKEpgSSMQkGAB+XuR2jz0YBRVlPXSWzKonVjbXbqKSkAAzGDSIPV0dnVc9SkUwBLAQAHcwceNOO9NwaGKPAEEEBGcdAT4qSRgBHIZAJxgtNE8oFxLDY7A4IHVaO8EJkYAB6VGaArIMCwKC0KqoHhmZ7Q2z2RxoPDBUJgcJtABEv3plHpQPpeniJRSMGpYQiOkZfGZMFZcnZDUYvNp-MFVHpMAAPiK2Sczhdrnp9CZOOiYABJGCXGhQNDg8wwUmwikuKV0gVMllsjkI7m2mUO5VimZZHlIEJ8tr2oWq85XG6UAUqmCnUMagycIA)